# how to make tags which are draggable but not editable inside input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

An which input contain tags and text, tags should not editable(can not delete and modify) and can move  around the text inside input. I attached a gif which show what I want to make.

[image: enter link description here]

I would be thankful for help.

Comment: please describe what you've done so far, and share some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What kind of library are you using in this gif example? It's not out-of-box JS/ReactJs

Comment: @alfian5229 - I have string of format like that "text {5} text here{3} text"  parts of string {5},{3} are tags. I made something like that by divided string into text and tags using regex. than inserting into a div text as inputs and tag as span element in same order. text an can be editable in input and tags are non-editable. To drag tags around inputs I am using react-beautiful-dnd. but problem is that i can not insert tags inside text at any position. here is image of what i have achieve so far. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yrkxZY6sMOemUuazBwy1_9Pjl4rugMeg/view